# Are Tor state files under /var/lib/tor functionally write-only?

Tags: server-administration

Does any of the tor software/infrastructure read `state` files under `/var/lib/tor`?  Or (unlike, say, [cache files](https://tor.stackexchange.com/q/13657/23144)) are they simply there for debugging/monitoring (and presumably can be removed at will)?

Answer (score 1):

Tor itself reads the state file, but I don't know of any other software that reads from it. The file is important for more than just debugging/monitoring, it's how tor keeps persistent state across restarts. This is useful for remembering its guard relays, tracking relay bandwidth usage for accounting purposes (and for server descriptors), etc.